# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number when trying to read json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I retrieve a json from google maps api like this

```
$http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+data.SimpleProfileForm.postcode+"&sensor=false")
                                    .success(function(data){
                                        console.log(data);
                                        user.location = data.results.0.address_components.3.long_name;
                                    })
                                    .error(function(data){
                                        console.log("there was an error with the postcode API");
                                        console.log(data);
                                    })
```

but I get the error unexpected number on this line:

```
user.location = data.results.0.address_components.3.long_name;
```

if i delete the numbers i get 'cannot read property "long_name" of undefined'.

How am i to access the data in the array? Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: could you provide the json response maybe? from this information we can't tell the structure of the response

Comment: If it's an array, you need to use the square bracket notation for accessing its elements: `user.location = data.results[0].address_components[3].long_name;` The dot notation is used for non-numeric properties of objects.

Answer (score 4):

You can't index arrays with dot-notation.

Your line of code should probably read:

```
user.location = data.results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

When iterating through JSON you can not reference # keys directly.

ex: `getJSONitem = parent.221.grandchild.0`

To get around this, you can reference the keys via their index as a string, since JSON keys are all strings.

ex: `getJSONitem = parent['221'].grandchild['0']`

You do not *have* to make them strings, but I think it is safer practice in case they contain random characters like "/-_" of the sort...